# Can I track button clicks without Google Tag Manager?

Tags: html, google-analytics, tags, analytics, usage-statistics

I want to track button clicks, which lead to external website. I want to put them in Google Analytics Goals.

Is there any option to this without Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Rather than write a bunch of extra code, you can follow this guide. Pretty simple. Your link text could be (most likely will be) different throughout your entire website. GTM will simply track every single click and report on it.

http://mediacause.org/track-button-clicks-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Wasn't the question how to do it WITHOUT Google Tag Manager?

Comment: This was 4 years ago, but I'm now realizing that I read the question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a separate .js file that listens for all link clicks on your website. Whenever a link click occurs check if the hostname matches your website. If not use the global ga() object (If you have added the analytics.js library snippet in your site) and send an event to google Analytics. The command will look like the one below

```
ga('send', 'event', 'outbound link', '{link text} - {link href}');
```

where {link text} is the text of the link and
{link href} is the href that the link points to.